# getDirty() Soft Deleted Item in deleted() Observer Method, Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, event-handling, delete-file, laravel-5.8, soft-delete

I want to delete an image every time I delete an item so I tried using an observer and put my code in deleted method, but I can't get deleted data although I'm using soft delete.

I already try this in my observer, but it fail.

```
public function deleted(Board $board)
{
    $thisBoard  = Board::withTrashed()->getDirty();
    $imageName  = $thisBoard['image'];

    Storage::delete("public/" . $board->getImageFolder() . $imageName);
    Storage::delete("public/" . $board->getImageFolder() . "thumbnail/{$imageName}");
}
```

Is there any proper way to get the last soft-deleted data in the observer event?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create delete method in your model class to overwrite existing delete mothod. This way when you delete Board, it's image or entries for images you can delete at same time.

```
public function delete()
{
    $this->deleteBoardImages();
    return parent::delete();
}

public function deleteBoardImages()
{
    Model::where('board_id', $this->id)->delete(); // You write your delete image code here.
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what `Model::OfBoardId($this->id)` do? is this how we get deleted data id?

Comment: Because I need to get the image name from the database to delete my image in the storage

Comment: That was just for an example! Check now I have updated it for better understanding. & You can place your code to remove images there.

Comment: Okay, I did it thanks. I actually like this way better than making it in the observer, but I want to know too if I can getDirty() a soft deleted data, If you know it impossible or there's no way to do that then you can tell me.

Comment: At this moment, I don't have much idea about getDirty() but I will let you know if i find something useful.