# Soft deleting both rows from two tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship, soft-delete

I'm new to Laravel and  trying to soft-delete both rows from two tables.

Vehicles table,

id

license

brand

is_taken

Taken_bies table,

id

name

phone

vehicle_id

In vehicles table, if `is_taken` is true, I grab the id of vehicle and fill it to `vehicle_id` from taken_bies table with other information.

In my TakenBy model, I've implemented relationship as follow:

```
public function vehicle() {
return $this->belongsTo('App\Vehicle');
}
```

**My Requiremnet:**
If I soft-delete the vehicle, I want to delete the related taken_bies information from taken_bies table. How can I achieve that? I'm using Laravel 5.8. Thank you.

Comment: Check this answer it might help you with your problem. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498901/getdirty-soft-deleted-item-in-deleted-observer-method-laravel-5-8/58500901#58500901)

You can override your delete function and add code to delete take_bies row whenever vehicle table row deleted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically deleting related rows in Laravel (Eloquent ORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174070/automatically-deleting-related-rows-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can delete it like below

```
$vehicle = Vehicle::find(1);
$vehicle->taken_bies()->delete();
$vehicle->delete();
```